# Removing HTML from iframe in React JS

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe

Is there any way to remove a part of the HTML rendered by the iframe in React JS?

I have tried using document.getElementsByClassName to remove the specific part of HTML, but it is throwing an error.

Comment: You can't directly modify the content of an iframe as though it were part of the parent page.  If the framed page is under your control and on the same domain as the parent, you can use [`window.frames[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)  to access it.

Comment: I did not understand your point...can you please elaborate?

Comment: "...but it is throwing an error." What kind of error?

Answer (score -1):

No you can not do this, you need to change the page using React.